# header file error "need ')'" even code has it

Tags: c, header

I'm doing my school assignment using putty.

This is util.h file which instructor provided and I never changed.

```
/****************************************************/
/* File: util.h                                     */
/* Utility functions for the TINY compiler          */
/* Compiler Construction: Principles and Practice   */
/* Kenneth C. Louden                                */
/****************************************************/

#ifndef _UTIL_H_
#define _UTIL_H_

/* Procedure printToken prints a token 
 * and its lexeme to the listing file
 */
void printToken( TokenType, const char* );

/* Function newStmtNode creates a new statement
 * node for syntax tree construction
 */
TreeNode * newStmtNode(StmtKind);

/* Function newExpNode creates a new expression 
 * node for syntax tree construction
 */
TreeNode * newExpNode(ExpKind);

/* Function copyString allocates and makes a new
 * copy of an existing string
 */
char * copyString( char * );

/* procedure printTree prints a syntax tree to the 
 * listing file using indentation to indicate subtrees
 */
void printTree( TreeNode * );

#endif
```

But when put `make` commend in putty, it shows error which I think should never happen.

```
util.h:14.25: error: need ')'
util.h:14.26: error: need variable name
util.h:14.32: error:  not in argument list
util.h:14.32: error: need ';'
util.h:14.34: error: need variable name
util.h:14.35: error:  not in argument list
util.h:19.30: error: need ')'
util.h:19.31: error: need variable name
util.h:19.32: error:  not in argument list
util.h:24.28: error: need ')'
util.h:24.29: error: need variable name
util.h:24.30: error:  not in argument list
util.h:29.21: error: need ')'
util.h:29.23: error: need variable name
util.h:29.24: error:  not in argument list
util.h:34.23: error: need ')'
util.h:34.25: error: need variable name
util.h:34.26: error:  not in argument list
```

I have similar header file and they all shows similar error.
I guess that `TreeNode` or function that returns `*` occurs error.
I want to know why this happens, and how to fix it.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots, and especially not links to screenshots at other sites, in StackOverflow.  Instead edit the question (using the "Edit" link at the bottom of the question) and cut and paste the text into your question, with proper formatting.

Comment: However this header file doesn't define a number of types such as `TokenType`, `StmtKind`, `ExpKind`, or `TreeNode`.  That means you need to make sure these types are defined _before_ including this `util.h` header file.  Maybe the order in which you are `#include`-ing files in your source is wrong.

Comment: I edited my question! And thank you for your help!! I should find out some types that doesn't defined by util.h

Comment: This is not a Linux issue in particular, nor does it appear to have anything to do with `make` or makefiles.  By all appearances, it is a C issue (tags edited).

Comment: The header is deficient in that it does not provide for several custom type names it uses to be defined.  As a result, this header can be used only where the needed type definitions are in scope through some other provision.  The issue might be that you are trying to use it outside such a scope.

Comment: The issue might also be that there is an error in the code that attempts to `#include` this header.  We don't have enough information to make that determination.  This is where we ask for a [mre] that demonstrates the issue.